# Erlang cannot find .erlang file

Tags: erlang

This is my first Erlang project, so obviously I have a long way to go. My problem is that Erlang keeps looking for a file called ".erlang". Here, for example, is my first project incantation:

```
C:\Users\niels\Documents\Edev>mix new hello
=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Sep-2022::21:14:02.952000 ===
file:path_eval(["U:\\","c:/Users/niels/AppData/Roaming/erlang"],".erlang"): no such device or address

* creating README.md
* creating .formatter.exs
* creating .gitignore
* creating mix.exs
* creating lib
* creating lib/hello.ex
* creating test
* creating test/test_helper.exs
* creating test/hello_test.exs

Your Mix project was created successfully.
You can use "mix" to compile it, test it, and more:

    cd hello
    mix test

Run "mix help" for more commands.
```

My interpretation is that Erlang looks for the file ".erlang", first in the root of the U: drive (which Windows set up as my home folder) and then in my private "erlang" folder. The mix command seems to have worked but that error message annoys me. I did try to create an empty file ".erlang" and put it in my c:/Users/niels/AppData/Roaming/erlang folder but the error message persists.

Answer (score 0):

The mix tool you use is for Elixir not Erlang. The Erlang equivalent tool you need is rebar3.